# Proper Quantity into Cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just added a text field for quantity in my products listing.  Regardless of the number I enter in the text field, the cart will show just an increment of one for that click.  Of course, I haven't told it to do anything otherwise.  But, how do I? I can't find the solution anywhere.

Here's my cart add method :

```
 def add_product(product_id)
    line_items.find_or_initialize_by(product_id: product_id).increment(:quantity)
  end
```

and in LineItems #create :

```
def create
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
  quantity = params[:quantity]
```

Let me know if there is any other relevant code I can attach.  Thanks.

View Code

```
<%= image_tag(product.image.url, class: 'prodli-img') %>
      <h3><%= product.name %></h3>
      <p><%= product.description %></p>
      <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
      <!--<p> <%= product.colors %> </p>-->
      <div id= "text_field"><%= text_field_tag 'quantity' %> </div>
      <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(:product_id => product) %>
  <% end %>
```

LI create

```
def create
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
  @line_item.quantity = params[:quantity]


  respond_to do |format| 
    if @line_item.save
       format.html { redirect_to "/#products", notice: "Product added to cart!" }
       format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item,
        :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" } 
      format.xml { render :xml => @line_item.errors,
        :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily pass additional parameters with a "button_to"

This should work better

```
      <h3><%= product.name %></h3>
      <p><%= product.description %></p>
      <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
      <%= form_for :line_item, url: product_line_items_path(product) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field 'quantity' %>
      <%= f.submit 'Add to Cart' %>
      <% end %>
```

Your params in the create method will then look like...

```
=> {"utf8"=>"V",
 "authenticity_token"=>"blah blah"
 "line_item"=>{"quantity"=>"12"},
 "commit"=>"Add to Cart",
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"line_items",
 "product_id"=>"1"}
```

So you can retrieve the quantity with...

```
@line_item.quantity = params[:line_item][:quantity]
```

Comment: No more "undefined method [] for nil class" on add to cart, but when the cart itself is clicked to view, the "nil can't be coerced into float" is back.

Comment: Did you enter an amount on the view? 
Try this... `@line_item.quantity = params[:line_item][:quantity] || 1` which will substitute "1" if the quantity is nil.

Comment: That code, added in erb tags in my cart show, which is what I assume you meant by view, gives me this error again: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass, highlighting the new line.

Comment: You mean the code in my comment?  That should be in  your `create` method, replacing the third line.

Comment: That made it work. This problem was killing me. Can't thank you enough for sticking with me on this one, long after it earned you "points".

Comment: No problem we all need some support now and then. :)  Glad it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Quantity is an attribute of the @line_item object.

So you should be doing

```
@line_item.quantity = params[:quantity]
```

And when you save @line_item it will then have the new value stored.

Comment: Thank you Steve.  This code leads me to "nil can't be coerced into Float" with the line " total_price product.price * quantity "highlighted in a total_price method in LineItem model.

Comment: Right, that suggests that `params[:quantity]` contains nil.  Can you verify that your params hash is as you expected it to be?  Maybe include the code from your view?  There's a gem called `pry` that's useful for stopping execution and allowing you to inspect variables.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance as I'm new to this, but I don't know where to go with "verify that your params hash is as you expected it to be". Also, which view code should I paste? Thanks again.

Comment: The view code where they enter the quantity. I think you said it was a text field in the products listing.

Comment: As to how to verify your params hash, just do... `p params` after the def create, and in your server window (where you run rails s) you will be able to see the params printed out.

Comment: Added the view code and the entire line items create action.  If you have any more insight (I know I'm stretching out your time here) that would be great. Where exactly do I throw in "p params"? Thanks Steve.

Comment: In my better errors' "Request Parameters" is "{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"carts", "id"=>"73"}" if this is relevant.

Comment: I'd rather see parameters when "action" is "create", and you should be able to see it if you scroll up the "rails s" display.  In any case, I'm now inclined to think  you're passing quantity as a sub-hash of line item... could you try `@line_item.quantity = params[:line_item][:quantity]`

Comment: When I click to add an item to cart with that code added I get "undefined method [] for nil class"; request params -"product_id"=>"1", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"line_items"} in params.

Comment: So there's no quantity in params. Is your code on github?